Does the verse 51:56 transcends life on earth?
The human soul passes through 3 stages and reaches its final place.

Soul world.
Earthly life.
Barzakh/grave.
Paradise /hell

Relevant to purpose of  creation, Allah says He didn't create jinnkind and mankind except to worship him.(51:56)
We have report telling Prophet musa was worshipping (salat) in grave. [Meraj report]
We also have report telling Prophet ibrahim was found with his back resting on bayt al mamur. Most likely he was doing tawaf of al bayt al mamur or praying towards it.
Additionally We have report that the wife of Umar was doing ablution outside the palace of Umar in Jannah ( bukhari and muslim)
My question is since pious believers are seen worshipping Allah beyond the earthly life, does the verse of quran 51:56 transcends earthly life and cannot be restricted to worship on earth only?
Also it will be a bonus if any report is added to answer that mankind and jinn worshipped Allah in soul world too.

Add linked references to the multiple claims that you have added, this would increase the chances of a solution and make it alot easier to answer this question.
